# SqlDataProvider query against its own data?

Tags: f#

So I'm trying to query from a table where the row has an Id column and a parentId which links to a row in the same table. When a parent has no parent the parentId is equal to the Id

I've tried to query for the top level parent's only.

The SQL for this looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Organisation WHERE Id = ParentId
```

So I've tried to create the same query in F# using the SQL

```
let [<Literal>] connectionString = "Hidden for obvious reasons"

type sql = SqlDataProvider< 
              ConnectionString = connectionString,
              DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
              IndividualsAmount = 1000,
              UseOptionTypes = false >

let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()

let orgs = query {
            for org in ctx.Dbo.Organisation do
            where (org.Id = org.ParentId)
            select org }
            |> Seq.toArray
```

it compiles fine however on running I get the following Execption

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in FSharp.Core.dll

Additional information: variable 'org' of type 'FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

I dont understand the additional information, can anyone help\explain ?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the type provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been some temporary bug that has been fixed some time ago. If not, please add an issue to the GitHub site: https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider